# Converting time duration to seconds error

Tags: excel

i have a range of excel data in the format of hh:mm:ss which i convert to seconds by multiplying (ie A1*60*60*24).

However the range of excel data comes from a reporting server which can sometimes produce values which are incompatible. An example of this is the duration 24:00:60. This returns an error as the seconds value must be less than 60.

Is there a way to still convert this value to a total seconds value?

Thanks in advance for any help given on this!

Comment: Thanks Gary's Student, works perfectly!

Answer (score 1):

With your text string in **A1**, in another cell enter:

```
=--MID(A1,1,2)*60*60--MID(A1,4,2)*60+RIGHT(A1,2)
```

**NOTE:**   This will not work if **A1** contains a real time value.

EDIT#1:

This formula will work for normal times and text times:

```
=IFERROR(A1*24*60*60,--MID(A1,1,2)*60*60--MID(A1,4,2)*60+RIGHT(A1,2))
```